# move divs within a row to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row topRow" >
            <div class="col-md-3 upperMember">
                <img class="img-fluid upperMemberImg" 
src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 upperMember">
                <img class="img-fluid upperMemberImg col-md-offset-1" 
src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 upperMember">
                <img class="img-fluid upperMemberImg" 
src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to move this entire row to the center. I know you can make it a col-md-4 but that would increase the size of the image and I need the characteristics of col-md-3

Comment: where's your try in css?

Comment: Basically you need to add `col-md-offset-X` to the first `col-md-3`, but the container size is 12, and your columns are 9, and there's not `col-md-offset-1.5` class

Comment: you can work with offsets, like adding `col-md-offset-2` after the first `col-md-3`, but you won't get a perfect centering with a total of 9 (3+3+3)

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294708/what-is-the-use-of-the-offset-in-the-bootstrap

Comment: Your row is in the center.... you mean you're trying to center the images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap center 3 col-md-3 divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846378/bootstrap-center-3-col-md-3-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
.row.topRow {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it do though? Might be worth updating your code to explain

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#alignment

Basically `class="col-md-3 align-self-center"` will do the trick

To vertical align the row try `class="row align-items-center"`

Comment: that's for vertical alignment in grids supporting flexbox

Comment: Yes, flexbox will be the best solution to this question

Answer (score -2):

The simplest thing to do is to add `text-center` to the `.col-md-3` divs

```
<div class="col-md-3 upperMember text-center">
    ...
</div>
```